# INSERT stored procedure not accepting null value

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have executed a SqlDataReader from a SELECT stored procedure, and am holding those values, some of which may be null...without my knowing. I am trying to pass those values into the parameters of an INSERT stored procedure.

When I attempt to pass the value I recieve this error:

> *"Proccedure or function 'insbuRenewal' expects parameter
>   '@TransactionID', which was not supplied"*

My code:

```
try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        insbuRenewal.Parameters["@SolarID"].Value = (decimal)reader["SolarID"];
        insbuRenewal.Parameters["@ApplicationID"].Value
            = reader["ApplicationID"].ToDecimalOrNull();
        insbuRenewal.Parameters["@TransactionID"].Value
            = reader["TransactionID"].ToStringOrNull();
        insbuRenewal.Parameters["@Host"].Value
            = reader["Host"].ToStringOrNull();

    public static string ToStringOrNull(this object items)
    {
        if (items == null || items == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return items.ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: Because you are trying to insert `null` in c#, where you need to insert `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Would be helpful if you included the stored procedure as well

Comment: I believe to do this the parameter in the sproc has to had a default value. DO you have access to look a the code? See http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2004/02/18/75381.aspx

Comment: Do you really need the `.ToStringOrNull()` function? If the value of, e.g., `reader["ApplicationID"]` is already `DbNull.Value` then that will be passed.

Comment: The code is incomplete. Where do you call the ExecuteNonQuery?. Where do you define the parameters? Please show the complete relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the method you have if you did this:

```
insbuRenewal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionID",
    reader["TransactionID"].ToStringOrNull());
```

instead of:

```
insbuRenewal.Parameters["@TransactionID"].Value =
    reader["TransactionID"].ToStringOrNull();
```

The `AddWithValue` interface is a much better approach for **all** of your parameters. Don't add them up front; add them on demand.

---

As Yosi pointed out. All you really need is this:

```
insbuRenewal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionID", reader["TransactionID"]);
```

Comment: Even with `AddWithValue`, you still need to use `DBNull.Value` if the value is null. See my answer.

Comment: @gunr2171, that's just not true. I have hundreds of lines of code that send `null` in to the `AddWithValue` method and the database updates just as expected. Further, it works as expected in `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @gunr2171, it doesn't matter what that answer states. I do it. And it works.

Comment: Why casting a value (to string), when you know that later on, it will be converted again to another value (to int)

Comment: @Yosi, I don't care anything about that. I'm just stating that the code as is would work if he just leveraged `AddWithValue` because `null` is interpreted as expected.

Comment: @neoistheone, I know you say you are right, but I have found [so many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+addwithvalue+null) that say otherwise. At this point I'm just going to drop it and trust you.

Comment: @gunr2171, I got you. There are a lot of people that believe they *need* to do that. But a lot of people still believe they don't need to leverage the `using` statement with all of the ADO.NET objects. Does that make them right, just because you can find 1,000s of examples of bad or unnecessary code?

Comment: Hey. Thanks. I am a bit of a newb.  I use a lot of unnessessary code, because I haven't found the short cuts yet.  The AddWithValue worked well. Still perplexing why the AddWithValue doesnt need the datatypes or conversions...but doing each one individually does...

Comment: @user2784648, the reason is because the `AddWithValue` uses type inference. Or in other words, it looks at the type of the value you sent in and makes a determination for the platform it's connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @neoistheone's answer, you also need to pass in `DBNull.Value` if your value is null.

Take this extension method:

```
public static void AddParameter(this SqlCommand cmd, string name, object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
insbuRenewal.AddParam("@ApplicationID", 
    reader["ApplicationID"].ToDecimalOrNull());
```

Comment: There is not need to create a method for this purpose, why not specifying the types when you add the parameters?

Comment: @Yosi, I use this method _exclusively_ for adding parameters. I don't have to worry about conversion types, and if the value is null it will take care of it for me.

Comment: It's totally redundant, what extra functionality you get by that?

Comment: @Yosi, why else would you make a fuction? To reduce the number of times you have to write code! By using this one function _every single time_ I add a parameter, I save loads of time a) not checking if it's null, and b) not caring about the conversion data type. Plus, your solution does not account for the null values.

Comment: Of course that one of the main purposes of creating a function is reuse. but, there is no need to create a function here! This casting here IS PROVIDED FOR YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DBNull` instead of `null`. In general, you need to cast your objects to database types, this way `null` will be converted automatically to `DBNull`.

**You don't really need to do the casting yourself.**

You need to specify the database type when you add each parameter:

```
insbuRenewal.Parameters.Add(
    "@TransactionID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = "somestring..";
```

Comment: by specifying the value `SqlDbType.VarChar` when you add the parameter, a casting will be made from the `string` value that you assign to it.